# Redirect after Session timeout (Grails, Spring Security Core, Tomcat)

Tags: grails, spring-security, tomcat7

I have an application developed in **Grails** (v1.3.7) and we used **Spring Security Core** (v1.2.6) plugin for authentication. After building .war file, I have *deployed the application in a standard tomcat server* (v7.0.22). The application runs fine.

I know that I can configure Session timeout period in web.xml either before building the application or in the tomcat server itself. But, I want (additionally) to redirect any page to the log-in page automatically whenever the Session is timed out. Because, if the Session times out and users click on any links or simply refresh the current page, they get a tomcat error.

Can anyone suggest a way to resolve it easily? Is there any configuration (like expired-session-url) in **Tomcat** or **Spring Security Core** that does the job?

I have search in the plugin doc site, plugin blog site but nothing found. [This site](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Spring-Security-ACEGI-session-duration-td1570970.html) suggest that I would require to add a listener in code and I would hate to do that and would like to use a simple configuration like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979963/spring-security-session-timeout). Can anyone guide anything?

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Http is stateless protocol, and session is just a marker stored on client cookies (+ local db), and you can't handle this as an event. 'new client' and 'session expired' is the exactly same, it just means that you can't identify browser for current request. For most cases it means also that user is not authenticated (for raw Spring Security Core, at least)

For you case, you already have session expired handler, it's when you're getting this tomcat error. Just handle this error, and redirect user to login page.

Btw, if you have proper Spring Security configuration, it must redirect all non-authorized users to login page. And seems that you have made something wrong with your app architecture, if you have authenticated user, but still having some user datails in standard tomcat session. There at least two ways: avoid your own user session, or make some kind of session-based Spring Security authentication config.

Comment: Igor, you were right. I just needed to add @Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']) to all the controllers that did not require any specific User Roles (open for all Roles, but not anonymous). Controllers defined for specific Roles just work as expected.